# add multiple filters in a single expression in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

New to AngularJS & just trying to "add multiple filters in a single expression" but don't find a way to do it.

Eg.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

<p>The name is {{ name | uppercase }}</p>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John",
    $scope.coutry = "US"
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It is giving output as "name" is in "uppercase" but I want {{ name | uppercase + ", " + country | lowercase }} i.e. "name" should be in "uppercase" & "country"  should be in "lowercase".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to create custom filter to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you something looking for this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

<p>The name is {{ name | uppercase }} and country is {{coutry | lowercase}}</p>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John",
    $scope.coutry = "US"
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,
Yes, looking for the same but I wonder can we add multiple filters in a single expression.

Comment: Yes but you need to create your own filter.

Comment: yup, will try for custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can always concatenate filters like:

```
{{ yourText | filter1 | filter2 | filterN }}
```

Comment: Yes, we can add multiple filters on a single text, but cannot add multiple filters on different texts.
{{ your text 1 | filter 1 + "  " + your text 2 | filter 2 }}.

Answer (score 0):

To apply multiple filters to a text

```
{{ name | filter 1 | filter 2 | filter3 }}
```

To apply different filters to differents texts, you can't concatenate with +

```
{{ name | filter1 + " " + country | filter2 }}
```

This is the correct way

```
{{ name | filter1 }} {{ country | filter2 }}
{{ name | filter1 }},{{ country | filter2 }}
```